# Xamarin.Forms IMediaPicker WinPhone

Tags: android, windows-phone-8, camera, xamarin

I working on an app that will run on Android and Windows Phone 8.0.
This app must to be able to take photos.
I found an easy way to do that by using IMediaPicker.
However, it only works on Android.
On WinPhone the code below returns null.

```
mediaPicker = DependencyService.Get<IMediaPicker>();
```

How can I get IMediaPicker on WinPhone? Any example?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.
On WinPhone mediaPicker will be null. Then, it's necessary to get it from Resolver.

```
if (mediaPicker == null)
{
    mediaPicker = Resolver.Resolve<IDevice>().MediaPicker;
}
```

But, for this to work, it's necessary to initiate the Resolver on WinPhone app constructor, like this:

```
var resolverContainer = new SimpleContainer();
resolverContainer.Register<IDevice>(t => WindowsPhoneDevice.CurrentDevice).Register<IDisplay>(t => t.Resolve<IDevice>().Display);

Resolver.SetResolver(resolverContainer.GetResolver());
```

Hope it helps someone else.